# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal cookie name NeoLoad Script replay error

Tags: neoload

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal cookie name NeoLoad Script replay error

what am missing. when trying to replay recorded simple login and Logout script that is based on the .net application any possible answers Thanks in Advance